# Validar que una fecha ingresada no sea mayor a un año después de la fecha actual

Tags: angular

espero puedan ayudarme, en mi caso tengo dos datapicker, ahora bien lo que quiero esque cuando yo elija la primera fecha en el segundo datapicker solo me deje ingresar una fecha no mayor a un año, cómo podría hacer eso en Angular y typescript?

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que revises [como preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que sea mejor recibida tu pregunta, a la ves que pongas algo de codigo de lo que haz intentado hacer. saludos.

Comment: Debes de intentar hacer algo y ponerlo no vale no se hacerlo dime como es